# If a DFA'd player has two offers and rejects the higher one, will his original team be responsible for the difference between them?

Tags: mlb, finances

Shortstop Troy Tulowitski was recently "DFA"ed (Designated For Assignment) by the Toronto Blue Jays. He signed with the New York Yankees for the league minimum, $555,000 and the Blue Jays still have to pay the [difference](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16583/what-happens-when-a-baseball-player-is-dfaed-and-then-signs-with-another-team/20247#20247) between this figure and his contract salary of $20 million, or $19.445 million.

Suppose he had received, and rejected an offer from another team for $1 million. Would the Blue Jays still have to pay the whole difference of $19.445 million, or only $19 million ($20 million minus the $1 million higher offer)?

If the former, are there any other disincentives against someone rejecting a higher offer in favor of playing for a preferred team? (In a normal contract situation, a player needs to weigh the two considerations against each other, because no third party is "topping up" his salary.)